# /etc/crontab edited via copy and paste, how to revert back?

Tags: cron

I have made a mistake, I have edited /etc/crontab via copy and paste. And now those crontab entries are not working.

```
[root@process ~]# cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
*/5 * * * * root php /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/apn/httpdocs/sdkstatistics/callEveryFiveMinute.php 2>&1 /tmp/testlog.log
```

Later I studied, and found that I should not edit crontab via copy and
paste. Rather I have to use **crontab -e** to add crontab.

I have run the **crontab -l** command to show the current listing

```
[root@process ~]# crontab -l
7,17,27,37,47,57 *  *  *  * /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-poplockdb-clean
1,16,31,46  *   *   *   *   /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here, my last entry ***/5 * * * * root php /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/apn/httpdocs/sdkstatistics/callEveryFiveMinute.php 2>&1 /tmp/testlog.log** is not listed.

Now can i revert back to my previous state?
Or, better what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which distro or version of the cron daemon you are running, but it is likely that your cron maintains system crontab files (/etc/crontab) and also per-user crontab files.

The file that you are seeing when you run crontab -l (as root) is probably /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root which is where you want to make your changes, by using crontab -e

Without further information on your distro version or cron daemon, I won't go on, but it is possible you have broken the /etc/crontab as it has a slightly different syntax to the per-user crontab files. See

```
man cron 

man crontab
```

and

```
man 5 crontab
```

for more details on your cron daemon configuration, then remove the erroneous line from /etc/crontab and either add it one of to the /etc/cron.* directories or to a users crontab file. You may find information on the error in /etc/crontab from the system log files in /var/log

Comment: Also, consider running your job as a non root user if root is not entirely necessary.